# Company name matching Common Crawl using mrjob

Tags: python, mrjob, common-crawl

I have a list of company name and details like ph.no, address, email etc.,. I want to get their company_url. We thought of using google API to make requests but it turns out to be costly.

After searching I found Common_Crawl which was somewhat close to google in website dumb data wise.

I found a [website](https://engineeringblog.yelp.com/2015/03/analyzing-the-web-for-the-price-of-a-sandwich.html#TODO) to actually map our phone number with the available phone numbers in Common_Crawl.

I need to find a way to match them using Company name.

Is there any way my which I can map by Company name with Common_crawl data. I don't want to look through 3.25 billion common_crawl records for each company name.

Comment: I have a person in contact of me who can help you. unfortunately, he is not a member of stackoverflow. If you want to achieve the desired result, then I think he has a mechanism. Let me know your response. Hope that he would talk with you.

Comment: @JafferWilson it would be great if your friend can help me out. My mail id is vignesh.kalaibe@gmail.com

Comment: I will share your contact with my friend.